# Ruby-Serialport: Listening to input

Tags: ruby, serial-port

I'm planning on moving into coding around the input from serial devices soon and was quite happy to find [Ruby-serialport](http://ruby-serialport.rubyforge.org/). The API looks easy to use, but I'm a bit confused on how to take an event-based approach towards receiving data.

I want to do something on data whenever a `\n` appears, but the current read() in the library appears to just dump whatever is on the screen. What I'm really looking for is a way to tigger a function it when new data comes in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby and the OS already handle the event-driven part of serial I/O for you.

The `SerialPort` class implemented by your gem is a child of `IO`, so it will already handle reading up to newlines...something like this:

```
sp = SerialPort.new "/dev/my-modem", 9600
...
while s = sp.gets
  ..
end
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks man! So that would put the whole line as s for each iteration?

Comment: puts(s) # the question seems too easy, possibly I misunderstood. I'm glad you are using Ruby!  Keep asking the questions...

Comment: Thanks @digitalross, it's nice to get a positive comment around here every once in a while =)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to create another thread in your application listening to data.

Then you should handle incoming data - put into some kind of array.

Use Observer design pattern to track state of the array with data - then you will have your functionality - remember that ruby isn't event driven language.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what would be a better language to approach this with then? I didn't pick it out of favoritism, just ease of use.

Comment: How is Ruby any more or less "event-driven" than any other popular programming language?

Comment: It looks like the comment we were all responding too ("Ruby is not event-driven") has been deleted. I want to thank the original commenter for reinvestigating.